# How to make predications based on past pair-wise comparisons

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, prediction

**How can I predict the score that a non-present observer would have given, if they were present, based on past observations?**

I have five participants/observers (A B C D E).

They are required to watch a group of dogs and score them on various factors (e.g. happiness, playfullness, calmness). Each incident of watching and scoring is an 'observation'.

Observers perform these unique observations in pairs (AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE). Therefore each observation is made by only 2 of the 5 observers. Each pairing complete multiple observations together.

Based on the scores from paired observations, how can I predice what a non-present observer might have scored if they took part in that observation?

E.g. Obvervation#21 was conducted by AB. What scores can we predict that C, D, and E, would have given. This would be based on past observations. Perhaps for "happiness" C tends to score higher than A, but lower than B, so their score would be somewhere in the middle.

*Additional info:*

- For simplicity we could perhaps consider it for one factor (e.g. happiness) and I could then predict each factor independently, though there is undoubtely some cross-over.
- The end goal is to determine if video assessments are adequate to replace 'live' observations. All participants will view a video of every observation, which I will then compare to their predicted scores. For now, I'm concerned about how to make the predictions.
- My original thoughts on this were along the lines of Network Meta Analysis, thought it would essentially need an extra dimension and become a tier of multiple NMAs
- Discussions tend to lead to regression, but I don't understand how it would cope with missing values that would come into play.

I hope that makes sense. It can be a bit tricky to word.